# How to fix some tmux things (screen instead of xterm; function keys)?

Tags: emacs, colors, keyboard-shortcuts, tmux, xterm

Why does tmux change the terminal from xterm to screen, and how can I fix the resulting text color change in emacs? I think the easiest way would be to prevent it from changing to screen in the first place.

I can use `TERM=xterm emacs file.ext` to do it temporarily, but that's just a workaround that doesn't solve the root of the problem.

Furthermore, the function keys no longer work in emacs when using tmux. Instead of F3 and F4 being macro shortcuts, they just print a tilde as they would in the shell. This seems unrelated to xterm/screen mentioned above. What is happening here, and how I can fix this?

Comment: How are you running tmux? In a console? In an xterm? In a shell inside emacs? Some other way?

Comment: I use PuTTY to SSH into the company server. It's all through that console, which is xterm by default, which I found out by typing `echo $TERM` in the command line. Echoing that in tmux shows that screen is used instead.

Comment: tmux does indeed set TERM to "screen", but I'm not sure why that causes a problem for you. I can start emacs in a tmux (inside a shell that I get by running ssh in an xterm) and get some coloring. It's definitely less than what I get with emacs in a graphical environment, but that is to be expected. What coloring problems do you encounter? <F3> and <F4> behave normally. But I don't use Putty to ssh, I just use the ssh cli client. It may be that Putty takes over some function keys. BTW, please update the question and add all the relevant info to it, not just in a comment.

Comment: [This page](https://www.ezeelogin.com/kb/article.php?id=40) might help in getting Putty to behave re. function keys.

Comment: When I undo it by using `TERM=xterm emacs file.ext`, both problems don't exist, so I assume "screen" is the problem. The coloring is simply off, like using the same color for comments and a few keywords, which makes the code look like a mess. PuTTY is not the issue because everything works fine with it under xterm--be it outside tmux or when I use `TERM=xterm emacs file.ext`.

Comment: As I said, Putty seems to be the issue with the function keys, not the coloring. But FWIW, I don't see the coloring problems you describe: without modifying TERM inside tmux, emacs displays colors reasonably well for me.

Answer (score 3):

**`tmux`** sets `TERM` to **`screen`** because that terminal description is limited to things that `tmux` knows how to work with.  Like **`screen`**, **`tmux`** translates features from the outer terminal description to the inner.

If a special key (function-key, cursor-key, etc) does not have an exact match in the terminal description, **`tmux`** will ***ignore*** it.

The default configuration for **`PuTTY`** sends ***different*** escape sequences for F1-F4.  The sequences which **`PuTTY`** sends are ***not*** in the terminal description for **`xterm`**.

Here's a comparison of the two (as a CSV file, but readable enough):

```
NAME,putty,xterm
kf1,\E[11~,\EOP
kf2,\E[12~,\EOQ
kf3,\E[13~,\EOR
kf4,\E[14~,\EOS
kf5,\E[15~,\E[15~
kf6,\E[17~,\E[17~
kf7,\E[18~,\E[18~
kf8,\E[19~,\E[19~
kf9,\E[20~,\E[20~
kf10,\E[21~,\E[21~
kf11,\E[23~,\E[23~
kf12,\E[24~,\E[24~
kf13,\E[25~,\E[1;2P
kf14,\E[26~,\E[1;2Q
kf15,\E[28~,\E[1;2R
kf16,\E[29~,\E[1;2S
kf17,\E[31~,\E[15;2~
kf18,\E[32~,\E[17;2~
kf19,\E[33~,\E[18;2~
kf20,\E[34~,\E[19;2~
```

You'd have trouble getting PuTTY to send F13-F20, but will certainly run into trouble using PuTTY and tmux with `TERM=xterm`.

Regarding ***colors***, the same issue applies.  The screen terminal description tells applications that the terminal can support 8 colors, and tells how to display those eight colors.  If your external terminal can do more, then tmux and screen hide that.

The conversion is not perfect.  GNU **`screen`** has a feature where it looks for a corresponding **`screen.$TERM`** terminal description (i.e., concatenating the outer **`TERM`** value to **`screen`**).  **`tmux`** does not do that: it makes assumptions regarding **`xterm`**.  But PuTTY is not **`xterm`**...

ncurses has several of those concatenated terminal-names for terminal descriptions, but no one has suggested a way for `tmux` to use them automatically.

Comment: So why does using screen change colors and function key inputs compared to xterm? The problem does not seem to be with PuTTY, as everything works perfectly fine before using tmux or when I use `TERM=xterm emacs file.ext` inside tmux.